# Why is the order specified in grid-template-areas not formatting correctly? it partially works but the aside tag is not going to the correct spot

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need the aside tag to be under the (section header) and (.summary), then have the rest of the content underneath that. You will see in the grid-template-areas that the order should be "#zen-intro:first-child", ".sidebar", "#zen-intro:nth-child(2)", "#zen-supporting". I think I am specifying directly. I have to only change the CSS. Otherwise I would have definitely redone the HTML.

```
.page-wrapper {
  margin: 3em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "#zen-intro:first-child" 
    ".sidebar" 
    "#zen-intro:nth-child(2)" 
    "#zen-supporting";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body id="css-zen-garden">
    <div class="page-wrapper">

        <section class="intro" id="zen-intro">
            <header role="banner">
                <p>header stuff</p>
            </header>

            <div class="summary" id="zen-summary" role="article">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>

            <div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="main supporting" id="zen-supporting" role="main">
            <div class="explanation" id="zen-explanation" role="article">
                <p>content</p>
            </div>

            <div class="participation" id="zen-participation" role="article">
                <p>content</p>
            </div>

            <div class="benefits" id="zen-benefits" role="article">
               
                <p>content</p>
            </div>

            <div class="requirements" id="zen-requirements" role="article">
            <p>content</p>

            <footer>
                <p>footer stuff</p>
            </footer>

        </div>


        <aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
            <div class="wrapper">
                 <p>Nav stuff</p>
            </div>
        </aside>


    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

aside displayed by footer:

[image: aside displayed by footer]

Needs to display under (section header) and (.summary):

[image: Needs to display under (section header) and (.summary)]

Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/GRIMROOT/pen/mdEzwYO)

Comment: Are you sure this is a *Minimal* reproducible example? See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Well it has all the html, css, picture for what is happening, pictures for desired effect, a codepen, and an explanation. I dont know how to shorten this with out you losing the ability to understand the problem or even a solution. You could simply open the codepen and perform edits for testing directly. My CSS also has Notes separating the different portions.

Comment: For starters, removing code comments (or entire blocks of commented-out code) helps reduce lines. Second, when your issue is a layout-based one, then a *minimal* example will not include superfluous styles like `box-shadow`, `color`, `font-family`, etc. Likewise `<head>` content is almost always completely unnecessary, as are a lot of parts of markup within the body. The rule of thumb is: if you can remove a line of code and the problem remains, then it isn't necessary to reproduce the error and therefore a minimal reproducible example will not contain it.

Comment: Following the above method results in a minimal reproducible example and, more often than not (at least for HTML/CSS issues), allows a user to realize the error themselves. Most of the time I see a problem or lack of understanding simply because OP did not create a *minimal* reproducible example; they just put everything into the question and assumed/ignored the minimal part.

Comment: I deleted much of the content now.

Comment: Do ypu mean something like this? https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/VwjVdjM?editors=1010